# Doctrine + SQL Server Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, doctrine, procedures

How can I call a stored procedure using Doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine doesn't have support for stored procedures per se. The exact method depends on doctrine version, but the best thing to do is to use doctrine native interface and call the proc directly with results eventually mapped to a domain class, if needed.